# Laravel Remember Me cookie not being auto filled input

Tags: cookies, laravel-5, laravel-5.1, remember-me

I'm trying auth attempt for remember me functionality in login form ..i implemented ed everything regarding remember me..but my form is not auto fill the user_name and password..Every time i need to type user_name.But the cookies are set in browser and as well remember_token is updated in user table. Below are my code

```
View
<input  type="checkbox"  class="input-field form-control remember" name="remember" /> Remember me

Login Controller :
    $auth = Auth::attempt($data, $remember);

config/session.php

    'driver' => env('SESSION_DRIVER', 'cookie')

Model Users.php      :

 public function getReminderEmail(){
        return $this->email;
    }

    public function getRememberToken(){
        return $this->remember_token;
    }

    public function setRememberToken($value){
        $this->remember_token = $value;
    }

    public function getRememberTokenName(){
        return 'remember_token';
    }
```

What i have missed in this?

Answer (score 0):

The "Remember me" functionality is to log you in automatically if you visit the site after your session has expired and not to remember the username and password strings in the login form.

Comment: The site is not automatically log me even if i set the 'Remember me'

Comment: The remember functionality is turned on with the second parameter in the function `Auth::Attempt($credentials, Input::get('remember'))`. You will need to pass your checkbox form variable into this parameter.

Comment: I have added $remember = (Input::has('remember')) ? true : false;